# Filling NA values using the populated values within subgroups

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have the following data.frame:

```
name  nav_status   destination
 A       5           MUMBAI
 A       0            NA
 A       1            NA
 B       5            NA
 B       0          NEW YORK
 B       1            NA
```

I intend to fill up the NA values with the value based on the name column.
I have tried:

1. Filling up `NA` values with last observation carried forward technique but then the data gets distorted. I used the `zoo` package and the `na.locf` syntax:

   `NEW <- na.locf(FINAL, fromLast = TRUE)`
2. I also tried to create a separate file and then use`gsub`, but it is not   generic and a separate file will have to be created every time as I have huge  data.

Expected result:

```
name  nav_status   destination
 A       5           MUMBAI
 A       0           MUMBAI
 A       1           MUMBAI
 B       5          NEW YORK 
 B       0          NEW YORK
 B       1          NEW YORK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'name', do the `na.locf` in the forward direction on destination with `na.rm=FALSE` and then do this again in the reverse mode (`fromLast=TRUE`) and assign (`:=`) the output back to the same column.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, destination := na.locf(na.locf(destination, 
      na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE),  by = name]
df1
#   name nav_status destination
#1:    A          5      MUMBAI
#2:    A          0      MUMBAI
#3:    A          1      MUMBAI
#4:    B          5    NEW YORK
#5:    B          0    NEW YORK
#6:    B          1    NEW YORK
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(destination = destination[which(!is.na(destination))][1])
```

This populates the destination column with the first non-NA value of destination for each name.

```
    name nav_status destination
  (fctr)      (dbl)      (fctr)
1      A          5      MUMBAI
2      A          0      MUMBAI
3      A          1      MUMBAI
4      B          5    NEW YORK
5      B          0    NEW YORK
6      B          1    NEW YORK
```